Computing the FT $\mathcal{F}(e^{j\omega' t} \mathcal{F}(f(t))$
I am currently revisiting some Fourier analysis and I am working with a problem related to the questions I propose here. In essence I tried to prove the following using $f(t) = \delta (t)$, but I want to see whether I can generalize the results.
So, my question is whether we can write this Fourier transform in a neat way: $\mathcal{F}(e^{j \omega' t} \mathcal{F}(f(t)))$.
In particular, I tried using the following results from tabulated results by using the definition $f(t) = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty F(\omega)e^{j\omega t} d\omega$.
Let $F(\omega)= \mathcal{F}(f(t))$, then we can use two properties, namely that $\mathcal{F}(\mathcal{F}(F(t))) = 2\pi f(-\omega)$ and $\mathcal{F}(f(t)e^{j\omega_0 t}) = F(\omega-\omega_0)$.
Combining the two results, does this imply that
$$\mathcal{F}(e^{i\omega' t} \mathcal{F}(f(t))) = 2\pi f(-\omega-\omega')$$
And how would this result change if one instead defined the FT with a negated sign in $j\omega t$ instead? Meaning
$$f(t) = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty F(\omega)e^{-j\omega t} d\omega$$
Would this instead lead to
$$\mathcal{F}(e^{i\omega' t} \mathcal{F}(f(t))) = 2\pi f(\omega-\omega')$$
Thanks in advance!

If the Fourier transform is defined as $$
f(t) = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} F(\omega) e^{-j \omega t} \, d\omega
$$
in this case, the Fourier transform of $$
e^{j \omega' t}F(f(t))
$$
is $$
F(e^{i \omega' t}F(f(t))) = 2\pi f(\omega - \omega')
$$
↑You've solved it up to here
Finally,
case of $$
f(t) = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} F(\omega) e^{j \omega t} \, d\omega
$$ is
$$
F(e^{i \omega' t}F(f(t))) = 2\pi f(-\omega + \omega')
$$
case of
$$
f(t) = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} F(\omega) e^{-j \omega t} \, d\omega
$$ is
$$
F(e^{i \omega' t}F(f(t))) = 2\pi f(\omega - \omega')
$$
The frequency shift direction varies depending on the sign of the Fourier transform.
Thank you!
